# Database class and while loop

Tags: php, database, function, oop, mysqli

I have a PHP class for querying the database and taking results. I need to be able to loop through multiple rows, but I can't figure out how I'd do that with my current function. My function is:

```
        $data = mysqli_query($this->connectDB(), $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        return $row;
```

but there's no way to loop through rows that I've tried that doesn't crash the script. I've also tried `return mysqli_fetch_array($data);`, but that doesn't work either. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
return $array;
```

[php manual: mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)